# What is the proper method to append a DAO.Querydef to the DAO.Querydefs collection in Access 2007..?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to run the following code, but it does not work. I receive the error "3219: Invalid Operation". I'm sure I'm missing something, and it's obvious, and I'm going to feel dumb, but I can't spot it.

In pseudocode, this is what I wish to do:

1. Create a Querydef for a Pass-Through query.
2. Use the Querydef to open a Recordset.
3. Check the records to be certain the query works.
4. If all is well, append the Querydef to Querydefs.

Here is the code:

```
    Public Sub Test()

        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
        Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
        Dim name As String
        Dim conn As String
        Dim sql As String

        name = "TestQuery"

        conn = _
            "ODBC;" & _
            "DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};" & _
            "UID=REMOVED;" & _
            "PWD=REMOVED;" & _
            "SIGNON=1;" & _
            "QRYSTGLMT=-1;" & _
            "PKG=QGPL/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512;" & _
            "LANGUAGEID=ENU;" & _
            "DFTPKGLIB=QGPL;" & _
            "DBQ=QSYS2;" & _
            "SYSTEM=REMOVED;" & _
            "FILEDSN=REMOVED;"

        sql = _
            "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS """ & "SCHEMA" & """, " & _
            "TABLE_NAME AS ""TABLE"", " & _
            "ORDINAL_POSITION AS ""POS"", " & _
            "COLUMN_NAME AS ""COLUMN"", " & _
            "DATA_TYPE AS ""TYPE"", " & _
            "LENGTH AS ""LEN"", " & _
            "NUMERIC_SCALE AS ""SCALE"", " & _
            "COLUMN_TEXT AS ""DESCRIPTION"" " & _
            "FROM QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS " & _
            "WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='REMOVED' " & _
            "AND TABLE_NAME='REMOVED'"

        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef(name)

        qd.Connect = conn
        qd.sql = sql

        Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset(DAO.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenSnapshot)

        If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
            'check records to see if query worked as expected
            If True Then
                db.QueryDefs.Append qd 'Error 3219: Invalid Operation
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

If I modify this to read:

```
        Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
```

The OpenRecordset gives me error "3420: Object invalid or no longer set".

Comment: AFAIR, a querydef with a name is automatically appended to the Querydefs collection. `Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("")` would create a temp querydef.

Comment: You can't create querydefs, and decide if you want to append them later, as far  as I know. All querydefs need to be created with `db.CreateQueryDef`, and at that time you need to decide wether to append them to the querydefs collection. Obviously, you can create a temporary one (As @Andre says), and after you've tested it, create an identical permanent one.

Comment: Oh good grief. I see my error now. The line 'Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef(name)' actually creates AND APPENDS at the same time. I was thinking it created a virtual one in the variable 'qd'. I was trying to append a query def that had already been appended. [ #facepalm ]

Comment: Use the SQL statement to open recordset. The `If True` is nonsense. If WHAT is True? Just eliminate that `If Then`. I did some testing and even though the new query is created, it doesn't show in the Navigation Pane unless database is closed and reopened. Not even when I use the Refresh method. Name and sql are reserved words, should not use reserved words as names for anything. Better woud be strName and strSQL.  `Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef(strName, strSQL)`.

Comment: And don't create the query until the recordset count is tested.

Comment: Managed to get the query to reveal with: `DoCmd.SelectObject acQuery, "queryname", True`

Comment: That `If True` was there for some other test I was doing, but I become blind to it and accidentally included it in my post.

Comment: Yes, using the variable name `sql` is an old and bad habit of mine. I am aware it's a reserved word, though.

Comment: Yes, when making changes to collections that display objects in the navigation pane, those changes may not be visible. Sometimes pressing F5 successfully refreshes the NavPane to display the changes, but not always. However, the command `RefreshDatabaseWindow` **does** refresh it. I use this command frequently in this database I'm working on, and had I thought/remembered to use it in this case, I could've saved myself some #facepalming, lol.